# docker python app reading files from network share folder

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I deployed a python 3 app to a docker container and it is failing due to the following:

The app reads files from windows network share drive for processing.  The app runs fine when I run it from my windows machine, where I have access to the share drive.

In the remote Linux docker container, the app fails because it can't see the shared folder.

I would appreciate any advise or example on how to make the share drive visible to the docker container.   Right now, in the python code, I point to the share using the os package .... example: `os.listdir(path)` where path is

`\\\myshare.abc.com\myfolder`

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount shared storage inside docker container to access it.
Mount volumes like in `docker run` command:

```
docker run –volume-driver=nfs -v server/dir:/path/to/mount/point ...
```

where `server/dir` represents shared path and rest is path accessible inside container
Read more about volumes: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/